# The characteristic of the quotient fields of $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\ldots, x_n]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Let $R_n = \mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2, \ldots,x_n]$ be a $n$ variable polynomial ring. Given a maximal ideal $I$ of $R_n$, I want to find about the characteristic of the field $R_n/I.$

If $n=1$, it is well known that the maximal ideals are in the form of $(p, f(x))$ where $f(x)$ mod $p$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x].$ So $R_n/I$ will have characteristic $p$ for some prime $p$.

We may see that $R_n$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb Z$-algebra, and field of char $0$ contains rational numbers which is not finitely generated $\mathbb Z$-algebra, so it follows that $R_n$ has non zero characteristic.

I do not want to use the approach of finitely generated algebras, is there any way to deduce the same without using this approach?

Comment: While I don't agree with your argument for the non-zero characteristic, the claim is true. (In fact, the fields you are talking about are finite.) On the other side,  $(p,x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is a maximal ideal and the quotient field is the finite field with $p$ elements, so every prime is a possible characteristic.